# logout blank page in my website

Tags: php, logout

hello for years and I can not solve the problem I vldpersonals each dating site but every time I use the log out always blank page   this is my php file `lib.account_logout.php`  sorry for my bad English

```
//------------------------------------------------
// Log user out
//------------------------------------------------
$SESSION->logout();


//------------------------------------------------
// Redirect back to index page
//------------------------------------------------
redirect(VIR_PATH . "index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your logout page you need to define what `VIR_PATH` actually is, if this is a defined constant this needs to be set on every page it is used.

What is redirect? We need some more information here.

## Edit

SO wants to Redirect to the index page.

So:
<strike>redirect(VIR_PATH . "index.php");</strike>
becomes:

```
header("location: your URL here");
die();
```

example:

```
header("location:http://www.website.com/index.php");
die();
```

Comment: Do you think the OP question, as it is right now,  deserves any answer?

Comment: @PedroLobito I think the OP is not up to speed on how StackOverflow works and needs some assistance with defining what they actually want. I think not helping those who are brand new is not constructive to SO.

Comment: You've a point on that but you should have alerted the OP to the fact that his question wasn't made in a constructive way to SO.

Comment: @Samir20 can you edit your question and make it clear to ask exactly what you want us to help you with? cheers

Comment: hello thanks for the reply I want to redirect the page index.php

Comment: THIS MY CODE AND A SCRIPT MADE IN PHP AND PAGE TEMPLATES IN HTML I DID EVERYTHING BUT IS NOT ALWAYS BLANK PAGE                                                                                                        


//------------------------------------------------
// Redirect back to index page
//------------------------------------------------
redirect(VIR_PATH);


?>

Comment: I don't understand your comment, @Samir20 . Code doesn't look very good in comments, can you edit your original question, please?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following;

```
<?php
$url = "your url.com";
session_destory();
header("Location: {$url}");
die();
?>
```

Also always die afterwards, if used on its own its fine but if its in another file you need to call the die so it does not run the rest of the file.

Comment: to be honest, using the curly brackets is just messing up the readability, why not use simply: `header("location: ".$url);` ?

Answer (score 0):

hello I want to do to change the way the photo of the woman who has no images, and men who do not have pictures in the automatic script has just one picture for people who do not have pictures I want to do the way they do for men and women men avatar avatar for women

I want to change these two automatic image

```
<a href="{top.virtual_path}{member_profile_link}"><img src="{top.virtual_tpl_path}{session.template}/media/nonfotowoman.gif" alt="" border="0" /><br/></a>
<a href="{top.virtual_path}{member_profile_link}"><img src="{top.virtual_tpl_path}{session.template}/media/user_picture_none.gif" alt="" border="0" /><br/></a>
```

this is  member_sections_picture.tpl  this code

```
<!-- IF member_picture AND member_picture_active -->
<!-- IF member_picture_adult == "0" OR member_picture_adult AND session.can_view_adult_images AND session.showadult -->
    <!-- IF top.active_module == "member_profile" AND !member_profile_preview -->
        <a class="picture_zoom" href="{top.virtual_pic_path}{member_media_path}{member_picture_large}" id="profile_picture_{member_id}" target="_blank"><img src="{top.virtual_pic_path}{member_media_path}{member_picture_large}" alt="" border="0" /><br/></a>
        <div id="profile_picture_{member_id}_zoom" class="picture_zoom_in" style="display:none"><img src="{top.virtual_pic_path}{member_media_path}{member_picture_large}" alt="" border="0" /><br/></div>
    <!-- ELSE -->
        <a href="{top.virtual_path}{member_profile_link}"><img src="{top.virtual_pic_path}{member_media_path}{member_picture}" alt="" border="0" /><br/></a>
    <!-- ENDIF -->
<!-- ELSE -->
    <a href="{top.virtual_path}{member_profile_link}"><img src="{top.virtual_tpl_path}{session.template}/media/user_picture_adult.gif" alt="" border="0" /><br/></a>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```